# How to plot points vertically with unequally spaced x-axis ticks in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataset with hundreds of points (representing frequencies) that I collected from different geographic locations that looks something like this:

```
data <- read.csv(file)

data

label Site1 Site 2 Site 3 Site 4 Site 5 Site 6
1     0.5   0.8    0.2    0.1    0.05   0.6
2     0.4   0.7    0.1    0.08   0.04   0.5
3     0.6   0.9    0.15   0.2    0.07   0.55
4     0.3   0.75   0.25   0.09   0.3    0
5     0.7   0.85   0.3    0.15   0.15   0
```

I also have distances from one point to these geographic locations (Sites) that are:

```
0, 167, 171, 190, 221, 347, 629
```

I want to create a plot where the x-axis ticks/labels correspond to the distances, and the data points from Site1 are plotted vertically at x=167, points from Site2 are plotted at x=171 etc.
I tried:

```
plot("", "", xlim=c(0,700), ylim=c(0,1), main="Overlap", cex.axis=0.1)
axis(side=1, at=c(0, 167, 171, 190, 221, 347, 629), cex.axis=0.7, srt=90)
axis(side=2, at=c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0), cex.axis=0.7)
points(x=167, Data[, 1])
points(x=171, Data[, 2])
```

I wanted to create an empty plot and then add the data one at a time using `points` but I have two main problems. First, I don't want the empty plot to have any tick marks but I want the range to go up to 700. With the above code R plots tick marks at every 100. I tried `axes=F` but I got an error. Also, I get an error when I try to plot `points(x=167, Data[, 1])` (and all the other points) that says `Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ`. I was thinking I should call the first (main) plot with the first set of data points and then add the other points but I don't know how to do that without first setting the x-axis ticks, and I don't know how to set the ticks unless I use `axis`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Adding `xaxt="n"` will suppress plotting of the x axis. `points(x=167, Data[,1])` results in the error you listed because 167 is a vector of length 1 while `Data[,1]` is a vector of length equal to the number of rows in `Data`. If you want all the values plotted at x=167, then `points(x=rep(167,nrow(Data)), Data[,1])` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below will suppress the axes and plot points at each x-value. I've used fake data to illustrate. I've set up the data so that the column indices of `Data` correspond to the index positions of `xvals`.

```
# Fake data
set.seed(149)
Data = data.frame(label=1:10, replicate(6, runif(10)))
xvals = c(0, 167, 171, 190, 221, 347, 629)

# Initialize plot
plot(NULL, xlim=c(0,700), ylim=c(0,1), main="Overlap", 
     xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="x-label", ylab="y-label")
axis(side=1, at=xvals, cex.axis=0.7, srt=90)
axis(side=2, at=seq(0,1,0.2), cex.axis=0.7)

# Plot points at each x-value
for (i in xvals[-1]) {
  points(rep(i, nrow(Data)), Data[, match(i, xvals)])
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I was looking for!